# Simple save record to algolia without objectID

Tags: python, algolia

I'm trying to save a new object to my Algolia index without an objectID, but for some reason it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search.py", line 9, in <module>
    "picture": "pic.jpg"})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\algoliasearch\index.py", line 212, in save_object
    path = '/%s' % safe(obj['objectID'])
KeyError: 'objectID'
```

the python code that I'm using (based on docs):

```
from algoliasearch import algoliasearch

client = algoliasearch.Client("***", "***")
algolia_var = client.init_index('*****')


res = algolia_var.save_object({"age": "new",
    "categories": "new",
    "picture": "pic.jpg"})
```

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?  Shouldn't it generate the objectID automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_object` updates an existing object. You need the method `add_object` to add this object to the index and generate an id.

`res = algolia_var.add_object({"age": "new",
    "categories": "new",
    "picture": "pic.jpg"})`

Comment: You can also specify the `objectID` by adding an `objectID` attribute (working with both `save_object` and `add_object`). If you save/add twice an object with the same `objectID` -> it will update/override it.

Comment: thanks for you help guys - I was able to get it working finally :)  Any idea how I can return the new objectID generated created by the add_object function?